# i updated to windows build 16299.98 and genymotion devices do not rotate

Tags: rotation, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

I Updated windows to version 16299.98
After that, when I start Genymotion, virtual box asks me 4 times for UAC not once like before, also for starting each device, it asks me four more times for UAC.

After all, device will not rotate with message "Rotate Screen: the virtual device version is not compatible with this feature". I used rotation for this and other devices before windows update

My Genymotion version: 2.11.0 and 2.9.0

My VirtualBox Version: 5.1.30